# Question about the construction of Godement Resolution and flabby sheaves being acyclic

Tags: homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

I am reading an introductory book to Sheaf theory, a kind of gentle introduction, which is nice for the most part, comparing it with other more technical books on the subject, which I am not yet prepared to follow at the moment, because of the heavy machinery usually used from category theory. But this book often omits information which I find important for my understanding of the material.

As I am understanding the Godement resolution, we define a functor $C^0: Sh(X) \to Sh(X)$ which assigns to each sheaf $F$, a flabby sheaf $C^0(F): U \mapsto \prod_{x \in U} F_{x}$ where $F_{x}$ is the stalk of $F$ at $x$. And so to get the Godement resolution, we construct a sequence $0 \to F \to C^0(F) \to C^1(F)\to...$ , where $C^{n+1}(F):= C^0(coker(C^{n-1}(F)\to C^n(F)))$. However, the part that is omited in the book is the construction of the morphisms in the sequence, which I can only guess are compositions of canonical maps. So I imagine them to be the following: $\delta_{n}:C^n(F) \to C^{n+1}(F)$ given by, for a given open set $U\subset X$, $\delta_{n,U} = i_{n,U} \circ f_{n,U} \circ \pi_{n,U}$, where $\pi_{n,U}: \Gamma(U;C^n(F)) \to \frac{\Gamma(U;C^n(F))}{im(\delta_{n-1,U})}$ is the canonical quotient map, so that $\pi$ would be only a morphism between presheaves, $f_{n,U}$ is the natural preasheaf monomorphism between the presheaf $U \mapsto \frac{\Gamma(U;C^n(F))}{im(\delta_{n-1,U})}$ to its sheafification, which is $coker (\delta_{n-1,U})$, and $i_{n,U}$ is the natural sheaf monomorphism between $coker(\delta_{n-1,U})$ and $C^0(coker(\delta_{n-1,U})) = C^{n+1}(F)$.

However, as it seems to me, these definitions not only lead to an exact sequence, but also one where it is exact as a sequence of presheaves as well, and so any sheaf $F$ would be acyclic which I know is not right.

My question is then: Where am I not thinking correctly, and also, with the correct definitions, how do we get that any flabby sheaf is acyclic? I know that $\Gamma (U;\bullet)$ is an exact functor when the first non trivial sheaf in the starting short exact sequence is flabby, but how does that translate into it being exact for the whole Godement resolution?

I appreciate any help in advance :)

Comment: Why would the sequence be exact on global sections ? You have no control on the sheafification part in the formation of the sheaf cokernel, so I don't see why you would believe that the Godement sequence is exact as a sequence of presheaves.

Comment: As for the second part of your question, consider $D^n=\operatorname{coker}( C^{n-1}\to C^n)$, so that you have $C^{n+1}=C^0(D^i)$ and exact sequences $$0\to F^0\to C^0\to D^0\to 0$$ $$0\to D^0\to C^1\to D^1\to 0$$ $$...$$ $$0\to D^n\to C^{n+1}\to D^{n+1}\to 0$$ Now prove that in a short exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$, if $A$ and $B$ are flabby then so is $C$. By induction, if $F$ is flabby so are all the $D^i$ and so every short exact sequences above will be exact on global sections and thus the Godement complex will be exact on global sections.

Comment: @Roland What do you mean by "have no control over the sheafification"? Where did my reasoning fail?

Comment: Also, I don't believe that the Godement sequence is exact as a sequence of presheaves, I know it isn't. That is why my question is about where my reasoning fails, which is possibly right in the definition of the morphisms in the sequence, since I guessed their definition

Comment: You said "However, as it seems to me, these definitions not only lead to an exact sequence, but also one where it is exact as a sequence of presheaves". I don't see why you would believe that. In the construction of the differential of the Godement complex, you made it clear that there is the map from the presheaf cokernel to its sheafification, but you know nothing about that map. That is what I meant by "You have no control over the sheafification".

Comment: Oh I see, you claimed that the map $f_{n,U}$ is a monomorphism, but this is false in general. The map from a presheaf to its sheafification is neither injective nor surjective in general, and it isn't in this case. It is a monomorphism iff the presheaf is separated, but it may not be true here.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you for the note, I will take another look at this through that.